# changing the level order of all columns/variables in a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

sorry for asking another question, but I searched thoroughly and didn't quite find an satisfactory answer.

I got a subset `data.frame` with 6 columns, which are all `factors` holding likert scale data with 5 levels:

```
strongly disagree - disagree - neutral - agree - strongly agree
```

The problem is, that they are not ordered correctly *and* that in one case one level is missing.
So I know how I can correct the order of the columns separately:

```
data_frame$somecolumn <- 
ordered(data_frame$somecolumn, levels = c("strdisag", "disagree",  "neutral","agree","stragree"))
```

My Question is how can I replace: `data_frame$somecolumn` with an expression that will affect *all* columns in that `data.frame` not just a single variable.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "with an expression ..."? You want to replace a column with another?

Comment: With expression i mean something like "substr(names(data_frame)" or so ... so I can change ALL columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean something like this...

```
# Make some reproducible data
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame( replicate( 6 , sample( c("strdisag", "disagree",  "neutral","agree","stragree") , 5 , repl = TRUE ) ) )

#  Unordered factor variable
df[,1]
[1] disagree agree    neutral  stragree stragree
Levels: agree disagree neutral stragree

# Make list of ordered factor variables
out <- lapply( df , function(x) ordered(x, levels = c("strdisag", "disagree",  "neutral","agree","stragree") ) )

#  Combine into data.frame
res <- do.call( data.frame , out )
        X1       X2       X3       X4       X5       X6
1 disagree strdisag stragree stragree stragree    agree
2    agree  neutral  neutral disagree    agree  neutral
3  neutral stragree    agree strdisag    agree  neutral
4 stragree  neutral  neutral disagree stragree disagree
5 stragree  neutral strdisag stragree    agree strdisag

#  Check result
res[,1]
[1] disagree agree    neutral  stragree stragree
Levels: strdisag < disagree < neutral < agree < stragree
```